# how to insert a row inside a column in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, dart

[not able to figure out the middle column]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8kLD5.png

```dart
child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  height: double.infinity,
                  width: 100,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
                Container(
                  height: 100,
                  width: 100,
                  color: Colors.white,
                ),
                Container(
                  height: double.infinity,
                  width: 100,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
              ])
```

Comment: Hi Mridul! Welcome to SO. To get the most out of a question, try to be more specific with what you want to achieve and what you have tried so far. For example, "not able to figure out the middle column" can mean a lot of things. Does it mean "How can I add a third element to the middle column"? From the image I can also assume that the layout of the middle column is not how you want it. So maybe your question means "How can I make the middle column occupy the whole space?". The code does not seem to match the image. Taking time to formulate good questions ensures you get great help fast.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this will help:

```
child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
              children: <Widget>[
                Container(
                  height: double.infinity,
                  width: 100,
                  color: Colors.red,
                ),
                Column(
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Container(
                    height: 100,
                    width: 100,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  Container(
                    height: 100,
                    width: 100,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  ]
                )
                Container(
                  height: double.infinity,
                  width: 100,
                  color: Colors.blue,
                ),
              ])
```

Answer (score 0):

Just Put a Column in center  with **mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center**

```
 Row( mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween, children: [
              Container(
                height: double.infinity,
                width: 100,
                color: Colors.red,
              ), Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
              children: [
                Container( height: 100, width: 100, color: Colors.redAccent, ),
                Container( height: 100, width: 100, color: Colors.white, ),
              ],
            ), Container( height: double.infinity, width: 100, color: Colors.blue, ), ])
```